# jerky transition in Durandal

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, sammy.js, hottowel

I'm facing a strange issue.  I've set up multiple routes that hit the same view/viewmodel, but are filtered differently.  E.g.:

```
       router.mapNav('main/upcoming', 'viewmodels/items');
       router.mapNav('main/all', 'viewmodels/items');
       router.mapNav('main/archived', 'viewmodels/items');
```

the routing works fine and in the vm activate function I am doing the filtering to display the appropriate items:

```
function activate(r) {
    switch (r.routeInfo.url) {
        case 'main/upcoming': vm.filterType(1); break;
        case 'main/all': vm.filterType(2); break;
        case 'main/archived': vm.filterType(3); break;
    }
    return init();
}
```

finally, in the same vm, I have events for when the tabs are clicked (Upcoming, All, Archived), that toggle between the views:

```
function toggleUpcoming() {
    //vm.filterType(1);
    router.navigateTo('#/main/upcoming');
}

function toggleAll() {
    //vm.filterType(2);
    router.navigateTo('#/main/all');
}

function toggleArchived() {
    //vm.filterType(3);
    router.navigateTo('#/main/archived');
}
```

The init() function waits on multiple promises to finish before allowing the activate function to return.

This works, but when I click on a tab, the view immediately loads, then the transition happens and the view loads again, resulting in a very jerky effect.  Any ideas?

Comment: I narrowed the issue down to the items array, which is a ko.observableArray().  The problem is that as I push items to the array, they immediately show up on the view for some reason.  I thought the view waits till the activate function returns.  In my code, the activate function waits for a deferred to resolve before returning.  What could possible be going on?

Comment: BTW, making the array a non-observable resolves the issue, but I would really want it to be an observable array.

Comment: If the question now is how to populate an observable Array without triggering notification, then the answer would be: push items to myObservable() and when done call  `myObservable.valueHasMutated()`. Read more at http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rainer, but the issue is actually with how Durandal handles routes to the same view, not with KO.  I made a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534141/durandal-multiple-routes-one-viewmodel-view)

Comment: @AliB did you figure this out?  I'm encountering the same thing.

Comment: @SB2055 check my answer in the link above.  It's a KO issue, and the solution is quite easy.