# Durandal: Multiple Routes, One ViewModel/View

Tags: durandal, hottowel

I have 3 routes: items/one, items/two, and items/three and they're all pointing to 'items' vm/view.

in the items.js activate function, I'm checking the url, and based on that, I'm changing a filter:

```
function activate(r) {
        switch (r.routeInfo.url) {
            case 'items/one': vm.filterType(1); break;
            case 'items/two': vm.filterType(2); break;
            case 'items/three': vm.filterType(3); break;
        }
        return init(); //returns a promise
    }
```

The items view has a menu with buttons for one, two, and three.
Each button is linked to an action like this:

```
function clickOne() {
    router.navigateTo('#/items/one');
}
function clickTwo() {
    router.navigateTo('#/items/two');
}    
function clickThree() {
    router.navigateTo('#/items/three');
}
```

this all works and I get the right filter on the view.  However, I've noticed that if I'm on 'one', and then go to 'two', the ko-bound variables update in 'real-time', that is, as they're changing, and before the activate promise resolves, which causes the transition to happen twice (as the data is being grabbed, and after the activate function returns).

This only happens in this scenario, where the view and viewmodel are the same as the previous one.  I'm aware that this is a special case, and the router is probably handling the loading of the new route with areSameItem = true.  I could split the VMs/Views into three and try to inherit from a base model, but I was hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: Is it calling your `activate` function? does `filterType()` return a promise?

Comment: the    activate function gets called by the framework (Durandal) automatically when the router navigates to the view/vm.    filterType is just a ko.observable with integer values.

Comment: Ok, so an animation is being triggered when you set `filterType`? Is that from a subscriber? You might want to have that be part of `init()` so that the promise it returns work for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by simply removing the ko bindings before navigation using `ko.cleanNode()` on the items containing div.

Comment: Good to know. I'll have to give that I try next time I run into it.

Comment: where did you call cleanNode?  Did you have to re-add the bindings?

Comment: @Ely I called it just before the `router.navigateTo(...)`, so for example, if my div is called items, I would call `var items = $('#items')[0]; ko.cleanNode(items);`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your parent view you've a reference to `router.activeItem` with a `transition` e.g.

```
<!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem, 
    afterCompose: router.afterCompose, 
    transition: 'entrance'} -->
<!--/ko-->
```

then the entrance transition happens on every route you've setup to filter the current view.

But this transition should probably only happen on first time visit and from that point on only the view should be updated with the filtered data. One way to accomplish that would be to setup an observable `filterType` and use `filterType.subscribe` to call `router.navigateTo`with the skip parameter.

Something along the line:

```
var filterType = ko.observable();

filterType.subscribe(function (val) {
    // Create an entry in the history but don't activate the new route to prevent transition
    // router plugin expects this without leading '/' dash.
    router.navigateTo(location.pathname.substring(1) + '#items/' + filterType(), 'skip');
    activate();
});
```

**Please note** that the router plugin expects `skipRouteUrl` without leading `/` slash to compare the context.path. https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/blob/master/App/durandal/plugins/router.js#L402

Your experience might be different.

Last in order to support deep linking in `activate`:

```
function activate(routerdata) {
    // deep linking 
    if (routerdata && routerdata.filterType && (routerdata.filterType !== filterType() ) ) {
        filterType(routerdata.filterType);
    }

    return promise;
};
```

Comment: This works, but as you said, the transition is now gone, which gives a rough experience compared to the rest of the application.  Is there a way to add a transition effect (even if it's purely through jquery)? I tried using the beforeRemove and afterAdd bindings in KO templates, but those don't seem to work.

Comment: . e.g. `var isFetching = ko.observable(false)`, you would be able to set that to `true`in `subscribe`. in activate change return init() to $.when(init()).then(function(){ self.isFetching(false)});

Comment: Next try: 
You might consider adding `var isFetching = ko.observable(false)` to your VM. By setting it to `true`in `subscribe` you'd able to determine the start point for the animation. In `activate` instead of returning the promise changing it to `$.when(promise).then(function(){ ...});` would allow you set it back to `false`.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice technique to time an animation, but I can only probably show an animated loading icon, not a whole view transition where all the items fade/slide in at the same time like in the 'entrance' transition in Durandal.

Comment: Looks like this "simpler" alternative has to many drawbacks to be useful at the moment for this use case... at least until somebody is willing to do a deep dive into the view transition. You might revert to your initial idea to split into multiple view/vms.